# OSGI external configurator folder not loaded

Tags: java, osgi, configuration-files, apache-felix, enroute

Based on Configurator Specification in [OSGI Compendium](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.configurator.html) we can specify configuration using json files.

It is also mentioned that default config location can be changed from OSGI-INF/configurator to other places using @RequireConfigurator("resources/configs").

But it didn't work for me, I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Below a screenshot that shows where file is located and also the content of package-info.java

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your bundle contain the folder "resources/configs"?

Did you make sure to `-includeresource` that folder into your bundle under the name "resources/configs"?

For example:

`-includeresource: resources=src/main/resources`

Comment: Thanks @BJ. Yes it is, after reading felix configurator code i've been able to make it works this morning. The solution was to use "/configs/" but it seems that it depends on the classpath

Comment: Is there any possibility to make this config external

Comment: Just the initial configuration can be external: https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.configurator.html#d0e132120. Otherwise, the whole point is that bundles contain configuration resources. There is provision in the spec for configuration resource to exist in repositories, https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.configurator.html#d0e132411, but there is not currently any mechanism in the spec for installing those configuration resources in a framework.

Comment: Yes this is the answer that i was waiting for. Thanks @BJ